# How to make a angled arrow like this with gradient and transparent?

Tags: css

How to make a angled arrow  like this with gradient and transparent?

I made a block with gradient here. need help to convert into arrow.

### http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/aZ65c/2/

I need a compatible with ie8 compatibility

[image]

Comment: why you just don't create a .png or .gif? something more 'crossbrowserish'?

Comment: this arrow will be dynamic. width of arrow will not be same every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@jitendar; check this out i make it with pure css:

```
.button {width:70px;
    height:140px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.button:after {
    content:"";
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background: linear-gradient(left top, #cb60b3 0%,#c146a1 50%,#a80077 51%,#db36a4 100%);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    display:block;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:25px;
}
```

Check the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/aZ65c/7/

Comment: That's clever! Modified it a bit to make it look more like Jitendra's example: http://jsfiddle.net/9TKLn/

Comment: @Duopixel - when I increase or decrease the size of arrow. it changes the shading of gradient

Comment: You must change size with css transforms on `.button`, otherwise the gradient and positioning fall out of place.