# Creating an arrow box in css with gradient

Tags: html, css, gradient

I'm trying to create a box with an arrow in css and here is my results so far: http://dabblet.com/gist/4079318

As you can see, the gradient is not applied correctly to the arrow, and it used additional markup for the arrow. Does anyone else have a better solution?

Comment: I believe your question is related with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765370/how-to-make-a-angled-arrow-like-this-with-gradient-and-transparent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a rotated pseudo-element with a diagonal gradient:

```
.fancy-arrow:after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:25px;height:25px;
  background:#f00;
  position:absolute;
  right:-12px;top:5px;

  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top,  #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); 
  -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
  z-index:-1;
}
```

for demonstration purposes only with webkit prefixes. The same could be achieved in IEs with some filter-magic.

**[working Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/4079405)**

Comment: Thank you Christoph, that's an awesome approach.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution that does not need CSS3, but then again it is for single-colored boxes only: http://jsfiddle.net/T4A2Q/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#Box {
 width: 300px;
 height: 40px;
 background: #0094FF;
 border-color: #0094FF;
}

#Box:after {
 content: '';
 clear: both;
 float: right;
 margin-right: -20px;
 border-width: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-bottom-color: transparent;
 border-left-color: inherit;
 border-top-color: inherit;
 border-right-color: transparent;
}

#Box:before {
 content: '';
 clear: both;
 float: right;
 margin-right: -20px;
 border-width: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-bottom-color: inherit;
 border-left-color: inherit;
 border-top-color: transparent;
 border-right-color: transparent;
}

body {
 background: #FFF;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="Box">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is no need for 2 pseudo-elements, you just need 1 for that. Also i guess that the gradient is the key here.

Comment: Like I said, it is a non-CSS3 solution.

Comment: [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/T4A2Q/2/) with less than half the size of your code... ;)

Comment: the border trick is quite cool, but unfortunately pretty limited... with a rotated element you can go crazy with colors, border, box-shadows and so on. Of course with limited browser support, that's the trade-off.

Comment: @Christoph, Is clear:both really needed on #Box:after? On my layout, the arrow breaks on some situations and I can fix it by removing that piece (clear:both).

Comment: No its not. I just forgot to remove it since I took amberlamps and modified it.

Answer (score 0):

Text gradients are not well supported yet.

What you may have to do use is use the existing rectangle, then place a couple of white masks over the corners to form the arrow.

Comment: The text doesn't have to have gradient, just the box and arrow.